# What happens to the Stone-Cech compactification if you change "compact Hausdorff" to "compact"?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters, universal-property

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) if in the diagram below

Universal property and functoriality

we take a modification that any continuous map $f:X\to K$ where
$K$ is compact but not necessarily Hausdorff what would be our $\beta X$ (if $X$ is discrete) in this case instead of all ultrafilters over $X$? Would it always exist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, if you drop the Hausdorff condition when talking about the Stone-Cech compactification, then it never exists for any non-compact space.  Indeed, suppose $X$ is not compact and suppose there existed an initial continuous map $f:X\to Y$ to a compact space $Y$.  Consider the space $K$ obtained by adjoining two points $a,b$ to $X$ and declaring that a set is open in $K$ iff it is either an open subset of $X$ or is equal to all of $K$.  Then $K$ is compact and the inclusion map $i:X\to K$ would be continuous, so there would have to be a unique continuous $g:Y\to K$ such that $gf=i$.  In particular, this means that the image of $g$ contains all of $X$, and therefore must also contain at least one of $a$ and $b$ since the image of $g$ must be compact and $X$ is not compact.  But now define $g':Y\to K$ by $g'(y)=g(y)$ if $g(y)\in X$, $g'(y)=b$ if $g(y)=a$, and $g'(y)=a$ if $g(y)=b$.  This $g'$ is still continuous, since the open sets containing $a$ are the same as the open sets containing $b$.  Also, for any $x\in X$, $g(f(x))=x\in X$ so $g'(f(x))=x$ as well.  That is, $g'f=i$.  This contradicts the uniqueness of $g$.

From a categorical perspective, what's going on here is that compact spaces (unlike compact Hausdorff spaces) are not closed under limits in the category of topological spaces, and thus are not a reflective subcategory.  The issue is with equalizers: the equalizer of two maps between Hausdorff spaces is closed in the domain, and thus compact if the domain is compact.  However, the equalizer of two maps between compact spaces need not be compact.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if you also drop the uniqueness assumption on the extension, then the construction can be made for a large class of spaces (i.e. a large class of spaces do admit a *weakly* initial map to a compact space). On the other hand you can also find weakly initial (but not initial) maps into a more general class of compact spaces. For instance the Stone-Cech compactification is weakly intitial (not initial) for the class of regular compact spaces.

Comment: @Eric Where Hausdorfness in your detailed answer above appears and how it is used ?

Comment: @user3357120: It doesn't appear.  That's the whole point--we aren't requiring anything to be Hausdorff.

Comment: @EricWofsey OK, but where Hausdorfness would have been used so that your argument of non-uniqueness fails ?

Comment: The space $K$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @EricWofsey And how/where it is used that it is not Hausdorff ? Please note that I'm new to topology.

Comment: @EricWofsey Please, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895260/what-happens-to-the-stone-cech-compactification-if-you-change-compact-hausdorff)